# Is there a possibility to take 100 records then other 100 record from database table using LinQ and Take()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, code-first

Using Code First, Oracle database
I need to select first 100 recors if there are a big amount of data,
but I also need to have a possibility to get the rest records, so how to take next 100 recors starting from 101?

If there a possibility to do it using Linq Take()?

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();
List<int> newList = new List<int>();

myList = DBContext.MyTable.Where(x=>x.ID == someParam).Select(x=>x.ID).toList();
int recodCount = myList.Count();

if (recodCount > 1000)
{
    newList.AddRange(myList.Take(100));
}
else
{
    newList.AddRange(myList);
}
```

Comment: Have a look at Skip()

Comment: `database.Skip(100).Take(100);`

Comment: Use `ToList` as final statement, otherwise you are selecting all into memory

Comment: @TimSchmelter your comment above is incorrect..... they will not be materialized yet and the sudo sql will be generated but not executed... if you want to see the values in the debugger you need "ToList", in both they will loaded into mem

Comment: @Seabizkit. OP calls `ToList` twice. Well, the first time after a `Where` so already filtered. But he doesn't need two lists anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you need pagination you need to define pageIndex and pageSize

```
myList = DBContext.MyTable
                  .Where(x=>x.ID == someParam)
                  .Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize)
                  .Take(pageSize);
```

But if you want only to skip by 100 what you are missing is `Skip`: [**Enumerable.Skip Method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985(v=vs.110).aspx).

Like Tim said don't call ToList() in the begging this will select everything in the memory. Also don't call `Count()` to check `if(count > 100)`. You should do it with : `if(myList.Skip(number).Any())` this will be true if your collection has more records than number.

Comment: I need these record anyway... but still trying to accelerate performance... when I have newList I need another one, and I am trying to create it using Include().. so if I have 100 records and show them first (it works fastes) I have a hope that it will be anought for these 100 to get a needed information)

Comment: @Songaila okay don't call ToList in the begging check for count like I wrote and use skip in your if

Comment: And I am working with WPF... what about pageSize and pageIndex

Comment: But I caught the idea! Thanks

Comment: Don't forget to OrderBy.  If you don't OrderBy, then the ordering could be different between the two queries and you could see page1 items on page2.